# Look for location, tag(s) and category(ies) in an input form

Tags: mysql, web-applications

I'm trying to figure out how to do the following for this site I'm trying to build.  I have a service table, a category table, a tag table and a location table.  Each product belongs to a location (city) and it can have many categories and many tags.
My question is: "When a user tries to find a service with something like 'japanese restaurant cheap San Francisco', how could I know which part is the "location"?
I know I could use different boxes, but I'm trying to build it this way, and I wonder how sites like Yelp do it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Not sure it this helps, but, have a look through the Yahoo Developer Network site, I believe they have a tool for extracting locations from a given string. It *might* help.

Comment: I wasn't able to find it, but thanks anyway :)